# Boundary point is either an accumulation point or an isolated point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the following statement true?

> Let $A$ be non-empty set. If any point $x\in\partial A$ ($\partial A$ is the boundary of set $A$.) then $x$ is either an accumulation point ($x\in A$ or $x\notin A$) or an isolated point ($x\in A$).

Here is my proof:

Let $B_r(x)$ be the ball with radius $r>0$ and centered at $x$

$$x\in \partial A\Rightarrow \forall r>0, \exists y,z\in B_r(x), y\in A\cap z\in A^c\tag{*}$$

Case (1)

$\forall r>0,$ if $B_r(x)\cap \{y\}\neq \{x\},$ then $x$ is an accumulation point.

Case (2)

$\exists r>0,$ if $B_r(x)\cap \{y\}= \{x\},$ then $x$ is an isolated point.

Comment: Please add the definition of accumulation point and isolated point.

Comment: A point of $A$ which is not a limit point is an isolated point. $x\in \partial A$ and $x$ is not a limit point  of $A$ then $x\in A$.

Comment: Your statement as written is not clear.  Do you mean "an accumulation point of $A$"? And "an isolated point of $A$", or do you mean "an isolated point of $X$, where $X$ is the topological space containing $A$ as a subset?  Please edit your answer to clarify what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @PatrickR thank you, I have edited it, and hope this is clear.

Comment: right, so is this proof correct? @SouravGhosh

Comment: @MathFail Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point. The notion of accumulation point is always relative to a given set.  You cannot say "$x$ is an accumulation point" by itself.  You have to specify the corresponding set: $x$ is an accumulation point of a certain set (in this case I assume you mean $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$". Please edit your post again.

Comment: @MathFail  And same thing for "isolated point". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point